# understanding the correlation from heatmap

Tags: data-science, data-analysis

I am trying to find correlation between features. I am working with a kaggle data set and the author says RM (.7), LSTAT(-.74), PTRATIO(-.51) have a strong correlation with MEDV

My understanding is that we have high correlation if its value is closer to 1. i.e. darker tiles have high correlation.

any help is appreciated.

thanks[image: correlation heatmap for a housing dataset]

Answer (score -1):

Here read this: https://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/regression-analysis-how-do-i-interpret-r-squared-and-assess-the-goodness-of-fit

Know that R-squared can have a positive relationship or a negative relationship and that this relationship can be linear, quadratic, polynomial ect. The r-squared measure indicates how well the equation fits the data by assessing the ordinary least squares which is the sum of the residuals also know as variance. Basically, it measures how far off is your average prediction using the equation you used to fit the data.

Comment: Thank  you for your response. But, i am trying to understand the correlation by looking at the heatmap.

Comment: The R-squared is the color-coded value so yellow is a strong negative correlation and dark blue is a strong positive correlation

Comment: Thank you.. I didn't take negative correlation  into account.